# How to handle off-topic, but self-answered and good looking questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

Should self-answered, correct or at least good looking, but still off-topic questions be VTC as all other off-topic? Wouldn't that be to rude against OP? Would such question be profitable anyway?

I don't have any example handy, but I thought about such situation. Someone asks a question and gives good formatted answer, that is correct and can be (?) profitable for future users, but is in the same time directly off-topic, because for example covers very large area or is opinion-based.

For example: "*How to write a simplest URL shortener in Yii?*". Such question is blatantly too broad and also opinion based, but along with this question we're already getting a good quality, working answer and solution. Would that be future-profitable? Should I VTC such question as well?

Comment: Possibly related discussion on MSO: [Question and self answers (not canonical) that start with an off-topic question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380680/11107541). Possibly related on hinduism: [How to discourage users from posting self answered duplicate and off-topic questions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/29115)

Answer (score 5):

**1. Edit it.** - If you think the post can be edited to remain within the scope of the site, do so yourself, or leave a comment asking someone else (or the OP) to do so. Especially if the answer is targeted and of good quality, the question can be easily edit to match the answer.

**2. Migrate it.** - You can always flag to migrate it to a site where it would be considered on-topic. (Not enabled on beta sites, so you will have to flag it for a moderator)

**3. Add the soft-question tag** - Some sites (like Math SE) have a soft-question tag, which can be used for rather broad-based questions (Example: Do mathematicians, in the end, always agree).

**4. Vote to close.** - If neither option works, the community policy is to close the question. The answer maybe a really good (broad) response to a broad question, but that is not the kind of content hosted on Stack Exchange. It is a site for targeted Q&A only.

You can always save a copy of the content before it is removed, or even upload to a site that lets users do so. (For example, you could make a pdf and host it on Google Drive).

Then again, SE is run by the community; so if the community decides to make an exception for an exceptional post, so it will be.